# Use @SqlResultSetMapping to map entity that has a @OneToMany association with a non-PK referencedColumnName

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sqlresultsetmapping

I am trying to use a @SqlResultSetMapping to map a native-query-result into an Entity.
This entity happens to have a lazy loaded @OneToMany with a referencedColumnName that does not point to a PK. That @OneToMany is not relevant to my native query.

The problem is is when i execute the native query, i get:

```
The column name mycolumn18_20_0_ was not found in this ResultSet.
```

But if i remove the referencedColumnName from the @OneToMany, then it works.

This forces me to add a `mycolumn18_20_0_` to my native select.

How am i supposed to handle this situation? How do i map this `mycolumn18_20_0_` in my @SqlResultSetMapping.